# Gitlab - Always run build for every stage

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have 3 stages Build,DEV_DEPLOY,QA_DEPLOY

I want to run build for both the stages DEV_DEPLOY and QA_DEPLOY. Explained below in a screenshot. For me when i merge to QA only QA_DEPLOY is running build is not running.

Requirement - When a developer pushes the code Build and deploy to developement stage should run , when a team lead merge the branch from develop to qa branch again Build and Deploy to QA should run.

```
stages:
  - build_proj
  - dev_deploy        
  - qa_release    
  
build: 
  stage: build_proj
  script:
    -  run build  

dev_deploy: 
  stage: dev_develop
  environment: DEV
  only:
    - develop   
    
qa_release:    
  stage: qa_release 
  dependencies:
    - build_proj 
  environment: QA
  rules:
    - if:  $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if:  $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following rules in your pipeline:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy      
  
build: 
  stage: build
  script:
    -  echo "run build"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"' 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "release"'   

dev_deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy dev"
  environment: DEV
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
    
qa_release:    
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy release"
  environment: QA
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "release"'
```

- the `build` stage is only run when commits are made to `develop` and for merge-requests into the `release` branch
- the `dev_deploy` stage is only run for commits on `develop`
- the `qa_release` stage is only run for merge-requests into the `release` branch